# For websites using HTTPS, are files uploaded via POST encrypted?

Tags: python, file-upload, https, flask

I'm using the official Flask tutorial for learning how to [upload files](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/fileuploads/) to a web server and I noticed the use of `<input type=file>`. I did some research as to whether data submitted via POST is encrypted in HTTPS and it appears that is the case. Are files uploaded with `<input type=file>` included?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use https, the following parts **are** encrypted :

- The type of the request ( GET, POST, ... )
- The URI of the request (the path and the parameters)
- The headers of the request (cookies, ...)
- The body of the request ( POST parameters, files upload... )
- The headers of the answer
- The body of the answer

What is **not** encrypted :

- The IP and the port used by the client and the server
- The full name of the domain (Because of [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication))

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  The SSL/TLS encryption encryption encrypts the connection at a lower level -- everything sent through the "pipe" is encrypted.